# How to access node.js module in RequireJS (AMD) environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I have a front-end SPA using `RequireJS` (2.1.14) as module system.  It basically bootstrap and load `Backbone.Marionette` app.

In `main.js`:

```
require.config ({
  baseUrl: '/js',
  waitSeconds: 200,
  nodeRequire: require,
  paths: {
    jquery: '//cdn/jquery.min',        
    underscore:'//cdn/underscore-min',
    // more plugins
  },
  shim: {
      // shimming stuff
  }
});

require(['marionette',
    'vent',
    'config/template',
    'app',
    'routers/main'
   ],
function (Marionette,
      vent,
      Template,
      nrtApp
) {
'use strict';

nrtApp.module ('Public.Main', function (Main, nrtApp, Backbone,Marionette, $, _) {
  nrtApp.start ();

  // this is where the error is:
  requirejs (['config'], function (config) {
    if (typeof config !== 'undefined') {config.log ('ok!');}
  });

});

});
```

The issue is, I would like load some `npm` packages (e.g npm install config) from `RequireJS` module.  **`RequireJS` can't seem to find npm `node_modules` directory which is sitting at different directory than `RequireJS baseUrl` directory**.

Below is my directory structure:

```
my_project/
    app/
        public/
            js/
                main.js
                app.js
    node_modules/
        config/
```

Below is error message:

[image: script error]

It tried to load module from baseUrl directory.

How can I access npm module to from RequireJS module system in my use case?

Comment: From client you can only access public folder. What is config in node_modules? If that module is also working on client then you gonna have to copy it into public/js to use it.

Comment: @Molda config is a npm module.  Yes, I would want to use config in client app as well.

Answer (score 9):

**It is not possible to use RequireJS on the client (browser) to access files from `node_modules.`** Files under `node_modules` must first be copied to a location that is accessible (under the `public` folder) before the client can access them. The documentation says [RequireJS can access Node modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2), but this only works for *server-side* JavaScript (when you want to use RequireJS-style module syntax in Node).

**To use your `config` module in the client app, you must first transform it into a RequireJS-compatible module and copy it under `public`.** This article [explains how to automate this with package managers and build tools](http://dontkry.com/posts/code/using-npm-on-the-client-side.html), and contains the quote that finally fixed my broken understanding of RequireJS + Node:

> In order to use node modules on the browser you will need a build
>   tool. This might bother you. If this is a deal breaker then by all
>   means continue wasting your life copying and pasting code and
>   arranging your script tags.

Comment: The linked article does not seem to use RequireJS. In that case, adding `baseUrl: "../node_modules"` in RequireJS seems to be much straightforward, although it is still not explained why it is bad.

Comment: you can do it but you have to specifically name the paths in your configuration file and it won't autoload anything you don't specify

Comment: (They also have to be already browser-capable, otherwise you need to modify them with something like Browserify first)