# Bundle node_modules for browser and keep "app.js" untouched

Tags: npm, browserify, node-modules

js file that is using a npm node module `greetings` and I use my app.js in the browser with browserify:

[image]

My index.html looks like this:

[image]

I know that the source code of the file `app.js` is now embedded in the file `bundle.js`.

I have now the Requirement that my production code contains the `app.js` and a additional libary containing the node modules like this:

[image]

This means that the client gets the `app.js` file and the `bundle.js` file and that I now can use the node modules from my `app.js` like this:

[image]

Basically I just want a `bundle.js` that is used as libary for my `app.js` and contains the node modules in a way that I can include them in browser side JavaScript.

I also tired to use the client side file and module loader. `require.js` to load node_modules but according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808991/how-to-access-node-js-module-in-requirejs-amd-environment) it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use browserify's `-r` & `-x` options: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles

To compile your code, run:

```
browserify app.js -r ./greetings -o dist/bundle.js
browserify app.js -x ./greetings -o dist/app.js
```

`dist/bundle.js` will contain the `greetings` module, `dist/app.js` will contain your code.