# Monaco editor: Highlight syntax errors in Python

Tags: python, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I want to highlight Python syntax errors in browser.

I discovered there is [LSP implementation for Python](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server) and [LSP client for Monaco editor](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient).

Is there any way to connect them together?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?, if so could you sure the solution please.

Comment: @MossaDababesh unfortunately I didn't solve it

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to connect them together!
It is all about the [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/).

### First step: the Language Server

The first thing you need is a running server that will provide language-specific logic (such as autocompletion, validation, etc.).
As mentioned in your question, you can use [palantir's python-language-server](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server).
You can also find a list of existing language server implementations by language on [langserver.org](https://langserver.org/).

In LSP, client and server are meant to communicate via a [JSON-RPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/) websocket.
You can use [python-jsonrpc-server](https://github.com/palantir/python-jsonrpc-server) and execute [this python script](https://github.com/palantir/python-jsonrpc-server/blob/develop/examples/langserver_ext.py) to launch a python language server on your device:

```sh
python langserver_ext.py
```

This will host the language server on `ws://localhost:3000/python`.

### Second step: the Language Client

Monaco is initially part of VSCode. Most existing LSP client parts for Monaco are thus initially meant for VSCode, so you will need to use a bit of nodejs and npm.

There exist a lot of modules to link monaco and an LSP client, some with vscode, some not - and it becomes very time-consuming to get this sorted out.
Here is a list of modules I used and finally got to work:

- [@codingame/monaco-languageclient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codingame/monaco-languageclient)
- [@codingame/monaco-jsonrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codingame/monaco-jsonrpc)
- [normalize-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-url)
- [reconnecting-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-url)

#### Using server-side javascript on a browser

Now, the neat part: node modules are **server-side** javascript. Which means, you can't use them within a browser directly (see [It is not possible to use RequireJS on the client (browser) to access files from node_modules.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874543/10985072)).
You need to use a build tool, like [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) to transpile your node modules to be usable by a browser:

```
.../node_modules/@codingame/monaco-languageclient/lib$ browserify monaco-language-client.js monaco-services.js connection.js ../../monaco-jsonrpc/lib/connection.js -r ./vscode-compatibility.js:vscode > monaco-jsonrpc-languageclient.js
```

This will create a file named `monaco-jsonrpc-languageclient.js`, which we will use as a bundle for both monaco-languageclient and monaco-jsonrpc.
Notes:

- The `-r ./vscode-compatibility.js:vscode` tells browserify to use the `vscode-compatibility.js` file for every dependency to the `vscode` module (see [Unresolved dependencies to 'vscode' when wrapping monaco-languageclient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56644955/10985072)).
- We browserify these modules as a single bundle, to avoid multiple inclusions of some dependencies.

Now that you have a browser-compatible javascript file, you need to make needed components visible (ie. export them as `window` properties).
In `monaco-jsonrpc-languageclient.js`, search for places where MonacoLanguageClient, createConnection, MonacoServices, listen, ErrorAction, and CloseAction are exported. There, add a line to glabally export them:

```js
(...)
exports.MonacoLanguageClient = MonacoLanguageClient;
window.MonacoLanguageClient = MonacoLanguageClient; // Add this line
(...)
exports.createConnection = createConnection;
window.createConnection = createConnection; // Add this line
(...)
(MonacoServices = exports.MonacoServices || (exports.MonacoServices = {}));
window.MonacoServices = MonacoServices; // Add this line
(...)
etc.
```

Do the same operation for normalize-url:

```sh
.../node_modules/normalize-url/lib$ browserify index.js > normalizeurl.js
```

In `normalizeurl.js`, search for the place where normalizeUrl is exported. There (or, as default, at the end of the file), add a line to globally export it:

```js
window.normalizeUrl = normalizeUrl;
```

And you can do the same operation for reconnecting-websocket, or use the amd version that is shipped with the module.

Include `monaco-jsonrpc-languageclient.js`, `normalizeurl.js` and the browserified or AMD reconnecting-websocket module on your page.
For faster loading time, you can also minify them with a minifying tool (like [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js)).

Finally, we can create and connect the client:

```js
// From https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/master/example/src/client.ts
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Copyright (c) 2018 TypeFox GmbH (http://www.typefox.io). All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
 
MonacoServices.install(monaco); // This is what links everything with your monaco editors.

var url = 'ws://localhost:3000/python';
// Create the web socket.
var webSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(normalizeUrl(url), [], {
    maxReconnectionDelay: 10000,
    minReconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnectionDelayGrowFactor: 1.3,
    connectionTimeout: 10000,
    maxRetries: Infinity,
    debug: false
});

// Listen when the web socket is opened.
listen({
    webSocket,
    onConnection: function(connection) {
        // create and start the language client
        var languageClient = new MonacoLanguageClient({
            name: 'Python Language Client',
            clientOptions: {
                // use a language id as a document selector
                documentSelector: ['python'],
                // disable the default error handler
                errorHandler: {
                    error: () => ErrorAction.Continue,
                    closed: () => CloseAction.DoNotRestart
                }
            },
            // create a language client connection from the JSON RPC connection on demand
            connectionProvider: {
                get: (errorHandler, closeHandler) => {
                    return Promise.resolve(createConnection(connection, errorHandler, closeHandler));
                }
            }
        });
        var disposable = languageClient.start();
        connection.onClose(() => disposable.dispose());
    }
});
```