# How to implement java intellisense for monaco editor

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, monaco-editor

We are doing online code editor using monaco editor.
One of the requirement is to provide intellisense, or code auto-complete for java/python language. I searched so many resources, and can not find any useful resource on introduction how to make auto-complete working. some said using language server, but it is really difficult to make it work.
May I ask what is the best way to make auto-complete working for java language? Are there any good material that I can refer? Or can we just use some json files to make auto-complete work as well?

I read LSP4J protocol and I understand the philosophy and solution for language server, but now, my question is how to get data file. In another word, how to create CompleteItem objects and return?

Some resource said we need to build java language AST or Source processor(string processor)? Are there any java library I can use directly?

I don't want to use eclipse here, we need to provide our own service.

Thanks

Comment: Have you figured it out? It'd come in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Language Server Protocol, as described here for python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349842/10985072
For Java, you can use [georgewfraser's java-language-server](https://github.com/georgewfraser/java-language-server) for example.