# How to autocomplete groovy methods using monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I use monaco editor with groovy language.
How to autocomplete methods by type ?
e.g., defining a String var1 = "abc", when user types vars. , how to suggest the String related methods, such as .toString, .charArray, .length etc...

Comment: I am new to this and trying to get started with groovy on monaco. You said you use it. How? So far I found https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html which does not have groovy in the list of languages. And I found some groovy extensions for VS code. For example: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marlon407.code-groovy am I even on the right track and if so how do I connect the 2? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Language Server Protocol, as described here for python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349842/10985072
For Groovy, you can search [this list of language servers](https://langserver.org/) for Groovy language servers.