# How can i add auto completion to a browser based editor using monaco

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, editor, antlr, monaco-editor

So recently I wanted to create a browser based editor using `monaco` and `antlr` for a custom language. I followed this awesome tutorial https://tomassetti.me/writing-a-browser-based-editor-using-monaco-and-antlr/ .

Monaco already give suggestions when pressing ctrl + space but I want to add an intelligent auto completion (like intellisense) inside `monaco`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly recommend [Mike Lischke's C3 Code completion](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3)

Also, see [Strumenta Tutorial on using C3 Code completion](https://tomassetti.me/code-completion-with-antlr4-c3/)

There's a bit more to the details than can easily be contained in a StackOverflow answer, but the tutorial is good.

Monaco works with LSP (Language Server Protocol).  It should not be hard to find instructions on how to tie an LSP plugin into Monaco.  So far as how to do Code completion in a LSP plugin, [this tutorial (once again on the Strumenta site)](https://tomassetti.me/integrating-code-completion-in-visual-studio-code/) (specifically the “The Basics” section, covers how to tie in to the LSP code completion hooks).

Comment: Thanks for yous answer. Do you know how to integrate the completion code in monaco ?

Comment: I’ve amended my answer to address tie in with Monaco.  The details on this as well are a bit lengthy for a SO answer.

Comment: It's not Monaco that works with an LSP, but Visual Studio Code. Monaco only knows code completion providers.

Comment: Hmmm this page (https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) indicated that is was possible if the LSP was written in JavaScript.  *Possibly* I read too much into “possible”.  Thanks for clearing up.

Comment: Interesting, would love to know how that would work, since all I have seen so far is this completion provider registration. Or they mean you can use the LSP from a custom provider or similar ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah.., kind of suspect “possible” is a give away (a LOT of things are _possible_ with software).   Might get bored enough to look into trying it.

Comment: I managed to get LSP work with browser-based monaco (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349842/10985072))!

Answer (score 6):

Monaco supports registering an own completion provider. This is a per-language registration, but applies to all editor instances. Call [languages.registerCompletionItemProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registercompletionitemprovider) with an instance of your provider.

The provider class itself is pretty simply. Something like:

```js
export class CodeCompletionProvider implements languages.CompletionItemProvider {

    public readonly triggerCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.\\@(".split("");

    public provideCompletionItems(model: ITextModel, position: Position, context: CompletionContext,
        token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<CompletionList> {

            return {
                incomplete: false,
                suggestions: this.createInternalCompletionItems(replaceRange, model.editorMode),
            };
        }

        return services.getCodeCompletionItems(sourceContext, position);
    }

    public resolveCompletionItem(item: CompletionItem, token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<CompletionItem> {

        return item;
    }

}
```

The real work is to generate the completion items. One way is to use my [antlr4-c3 code](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3) completion core and amend that with logic to create and use a symbol table to provide symbol information.