# Monaco Editor and LSP written on Java

Tags: monaco-editor, language-server-protocol, monaco-languageserver

Is it really possible to connect Monaco editor with [Groovy Language Server](https://github.com/GroovyLanguageServer/groovy-language-server) using [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient)
as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702255/monaco-editor-highlight-syntax-errors-in-python/71349842#71349842) with Python?

Has someone seen any examples of this at all?